# java number of objects created by a class aside from using a profiler like an eclipse plugin

Tags: java, eclipse, object, profiler, yourkit

I was wondering if there is a good eclipse plugin to see how many objects are created or each class. Yourkit profiler does a good job at this but having something right in eclipse is handy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the [Eclipse Memory Analyzer](http://www.eclipse.org/mat/) plugin for Eclipse.